# Get a document image preview of specified size

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, owa, powerpoint-services

In our app we got previews from urls like:

```
https://sharepoint_server/_layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc=...&action=imagepreview
```

But the received images are too small.

In particular, I want to get high resolution thumbnails for PowerPoint presentation documents.

In other words, can I somehow get a thumbnail with a specified size by url using a `width` and/or `height` parameter for example:

```
https://sharepoint_server/_layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc=...&action=imagepreview&width=1280&height=720
```